# Issues with running remix Binary in Bazel sandbox

Tags: bazel, remix, bazel-rules, bazel-aspect

I've encountered an issue trying to use bazel as a build tool for remix. I've been able to run remix in dev mode but currently unable to get remix build to work.

I've encountered a few errors that led up to this point. I'll list the errors in the order which they occurred with my fixes (just incase any of the fixes introduces a new issue)

First error in the bazel sandbox is related to a transitive dependency of `@remix-run/dev` (`@remix-run/dev->gunzip-maybe->browserify-zlib`). Bazel failed to fetch the bazel repository `@npm__browserify-zlib__0.1.4`. I assumed this was a bazel issue and tried to override `browserify-zlib@0.1.4` with `browserify-zlib@0.2.0`, which worked. Here is bazel error for reference:

```
ERROR: /Users/emmanuel/projects/bbbazel/WORKSPACE:89:17: fetching _npm_import rule //external:npm__browserify-zlib__0.1.4: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/external/aspect_rules_js/npm/private/npm_import.bzl", line 471, column 27, in _impl
                pkg_json = json.decode(rctx.read(pkg_json_path))
Error in decode: at offset 685, object has duplicate key: "main"
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/external/npm/BUILD.bazel:3012:6: @npm//:npm__browserify-zlib__0.1.4_source_directory depends on @npm__browserify-zlib__0.1.4//:source_directory in repository @npm__browserify-zlib__0.1.4 which failed to fetch. no such package '@npm__browserify-zlib__0.1.4//': at offset 685, object has duplicate key: "main"
Next error in the bazel sandbox is related to another transitive dependency of @remix-run/dev (@remix-run/dev->xdm->deasync). The install lifecycle hook for the deasync npm package makes a call to the node-gyp binary which doesn't exist in the sandbox and the bazel build command fails during setup. To fix this, I disabled the install lifecycle hook (I also disabled it with a pnpm install outside the sandbox and the remix build command executed perfectly) which led to the final error. Here's the error message for this error:
/Users/emmanuel/projects/bbbazel/BUILD.bazel:5:22: Running lifecycle hooks on npm package deasync@0.1.28 failed: (Exit 1): lifecycle-hooks.sh failed: error executing command (from target //:.aspect_rules_js/node_modules/deasync@0.1.28/lc) bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/aspect_rules_js/npm/private/lifecycle/lifecycle-hooks.sh deasync ../../../external/npm__deasync__0.1.28/package ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/aspect_rules_js/npm/private/lifecycle/min/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: line 5: 1211: command not found
node-gyp not found! Please upgrade your install of npm! You need at least 1.1.5 (I think) and preferably 1.1.30.

> deasync@0.1.28 install /private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/deasync@0.1.28/node_modules/deasync
> node ./build.js

===============================================================
Failure while running lifecycle hook for package 'deasync@0.1.28':

  Script:  'install'
  Command: `node ./build.js`

Stack trace:

spawn ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/aspect_rules_js/npm/private/lifecycle/min/index.min.js:1:91930)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
The final error suggests a bug with remix, but since it only occurs in the bazel sandbox I think it may be an issue that cuts across bazel and remix. The error returned is shown below:
The following error is a bug in Remix; please open an issue! https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/new
Missing output for entry point
Error
    at Object.onCompileFailure (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1566/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/@remix-run+dev@1.12.0_@remix-run+serve@1.12.0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli/commands.js:180:13)
    at Object.compile (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1566/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/@remix-run+dev@1.12.0_@remix-run+serve@1.12.0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/compiler/remixCompiler.js:34:134)
    at async Object.build (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1566/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/@remix-run+dev@1.12.0_@remix-run+serve@1.12.0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/compiler/build.js:33:3)
    at async Object.build (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1566/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/@remix-run+dev@1.12.0_@remix-run+serve@1.12.0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli/commands.js:175:3)
    at async Object.run (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_emmanuel/f416ba8913b741927ac435783e3163e0/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1566/execroot/fleet/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/node_modules/.aspect_rules_js/@remix-run+dev@1.12.0_@remix-run+serve@1.12.0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli/run.js:449:7)
Building Remix app in production mode...
Target //examples/remix:build failed to build
```

I've tried to run it outside bazel and with `pnpm` (I added the override to the `package.json` for `browserify-zlip@0.2.0`, then I ran `pnpm instal` with `--ignore-scripts` flag) and it builds fine.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with remix or a bazel issue. Has anyone else experienced this? Or does anyone having a working version of remix with bazel as the build tool?

I've created a minified version of the repository in the state of the 3rd error https://github.com/noelenwenede/bbbazel. Start up instructions are in the readme file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the tar.gz of browserify-zlib@0.1.4 does indeed contains two json entries. You can fix that in bazel by patching the package.json as suggested in their docs:
https://docs.aspect.build/rules/aspect_rules_js/docs/faq#why-cant-bazel-fetch-an-npm-package